# How to get UserId for logging inside controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, asp.net-identity

I want to logging my AccountController and i don't want use `User.Identity.Name`, because i think UserName is sensitive information. Can i use `User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` for getting id few times per action and don't get problem with performance?

Comment: Yes, there should be no issues with performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i use `User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` for getting id
> few times per action and don't get problem with performance?

Yes, you can use it to get the id per action without any performance problem.

But the HttpContext isn't thread-safe. Reading or writing properties of the HttpContext outside of processing a request can result in a NullReferenceException. So, after getting the id, it is better to check whether it is Null or not.